# Portlet 2.0: No properties set on ResourceURL

Tags: java, url, resources, properties, portlet

I'm creating a ResourceURL, so I can serve a file through a portlet.

```
final ResourceURL resourceUrl = 
    facesHelper.getRenderResponse().createResourceURL();
resourceUrl.setProperty("download", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
resourceUrl.setProperty("format", "csv");
```

Unfortunately the URL looks this:

```
/portal/portal/default/noRoles/MyPortletNoSecurityWindow?action=b&cacheability=PAGE
```

I can see no properties.

When I'm in the [serveResource](http://www.bluesunrise.com/portlet-api/javax/portlet/ResourceServingPortlet.html#serveResource%28javax.portlet.ResourceRequest,%20javax.portlet.ResourceResponse%29) method of my portlet, the `getProperty()` on `download` returns `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thou shall use `setParameter` instead of `setProperty`.